# scheduledLocalNotifications array is empty

Tags: ios, nsarray, alert, uilocalnotification

```
    NSArray *notifs = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

I'm trying to store all my notifications in this array but it doesn't seem to work , the array is always empty , altough notifications do trigger.

Ok something seriously retarded is happening.

I have a slider mechanism which updated the notification hour preset ( how many hours before the actual date of an event should the user get a notification).

Let's say the user originally selects the hour of the event at 2PM and the preset is 1 , so the notification will fire at 1PM , all works fine.

The slider mechanism also does the following, when it is changed , i go through all my notifications and change the firedate so it's updated accordingly . Here is the code :

```
-(void)updateNotifications{
NSArray    notifs = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForNsLog = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatterForNsLog setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatterForNsLog setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSString *notificationHourNew = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"notificationHour"];
int notifHourNew = [notificationHourNew intValue];
int notifHourOld = [self.notificationHour intValue];

NSLog(@"Original notification hour is %d , and when exiting the view it is : %d",notifHourOld,notifHourNew);

int difference = notifHourOld - notifHourNew;
NSLog(@"The difference is : %d", difference);

if (difference != 0) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    for (UILocalNotification *notif in notifs) {
        notif.fireDate = [NotificationHelper fireDateOfLocalNotificationForDate:notif.fireDate byAddingNumberOfHours:difference];
        NSLog(@"Notification date is now:%@",[dateFormatterForNsLog stringFromDate:notif.fireDate]);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
    }
}
```

This is triggered in viewDidDissapear.

It works in only 1 case ( which i don't understand why) , if i increase the slider value. 
Example : Original preset is 4 , i make it 5 ( so now the notification will fire 5 hours before the event).

If i try to modify the preset to go from 5->4 (decrease) , the array is empty (LOL) and nothing works. Why?

edit : the method i use to alter the date:

```
+(NSDate*)fireDateOfLocalNotificationForDate:(NSDate *)date byAddingNumberOfHours:(int)hours{
NSDate *initialDate = date;
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

[comps setHour:+hours];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:initialDate options:0];

return fireDate;
```

}

Comment: The alloc/init of `notifs` is useless. Could you show us some logs? To understand in which loop/test if goes? Shouldn't difference be "new-old" instead?

Comment: 2014-04-19 14:18:37.558 AppName[2246:60b] Original notification hour is 6 , and when exiting the view it is : 8
2014-04-19 14:18:37.563 AppName[2246:60b] The difference is : -2

Comment: Not sure what logs  you need , also edited with the method i use to alter the date , i need old - new so i can use the setHours:+difference method .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this , the problem was the notification was being programmed in the past ( as in before [NSDate date ] - the current date ) , and i was trying to add hours to it but apparently apple deletes notifications that can't be fired because of a bad date automatically.